# x is damaged and cannot be opened. It should be moved to trash

Tags: high-sierra, imac

I have a 2010 iMac. One day I installed the "recommended security updates" and all of a sudden I had High Sierra installed on my iMac instead of El Capitan.

Now I cannot not open any pdf, jpeg png's and more. I think my preview app might be broken. I always get the message "x is damaged and cannot be opened. It should be moved to trash".

I have tried using the command `sudo spctl --master-disable` in terminal and turning off Gatekeeper but it isn't helping.

Apart from this problem the my Mac is running decently. We do have time machine backups to go back to when it was on El Capitan.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling High Sierra via the recovery partition? (Hold cmd+R after powering on your Mac)

Comment: @KevinGrabher I haven't. I'll give it a shot